# Returning auto-generated primary key after SQL insertion

Tags: primary-key, auto-increment, mysqli

I am trying to submit data to a database and then have it return the value of the user_id (primary key) created by the insertion, but I can't get it to return the value. I use the same query in phpAdmin and it works just fine. I know this should be simple, but I just can't get it. Here is my code:

(I do have values to connect to the database, just didn't include them for privacy.)

```
$dbc = @mysqli_connect (DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_SITE) 
OR die ('Could not connect to MYSQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error() );
$nameQuery="INSERT into nameReunion 
    (username, password,email,firstName,middleName,lastName, maidenName,     lastUpdate)
VALUES
('$username', '$password', '$email', '$fname', '$miname', '$lname', '$maname', CURDATE());";    

$r = @mysqli_query ($dbc, $nameQuery);


if(!$r) {
echo "The database was not updated.";
} else {
echo 'The connection was successful<br/>';
};

$getUserID="SELECT user_id FROM nameReunion WHERE username='$username';";
$r2=@mysqli_query ($dbc, $getUserID);
echo $r2;
echo $getUserID;
```

Please help. I have spent wayyy too much time on something I fear should be very simple.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I used mysqli_insert_id and it worked.  The documentation for this solution is available [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/apis-php/en/apis-php-mysqli.insert-id.html).

Comment: I edited this to include a link to the documentation. Could you please mark your answer as correct so that others with the same problem can find a solution in future, thanks. I know that you may have to wait a certain time to do this. Your question was nearly closed because it came quite close to being a "Googler" - i.e. simply solved by using the search engine. Take the tour and also check out the "help us to help you" blog (both at the bottom left of the page). BTW, welcome to the forum - it's a great resource if you make the effort to use it properly.